# ALGORITHM Multiplication of Integers from "discrete math and its applications 7th edition " book

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

[image]

Please can you help me to understand the "italic text"

**How many additions of bits and shifts of bits are used to multiply a and b using Algorithm 3"see the the attached photo"?**

Solution: Algorithm 3 computes the products of a and b by adding the partial products c0,c1,c2,...,and cn−1.Whenbj =1,wecomputethepartialproductcj byshiftingthebinary expansion of a by j bits. When bj = 0, no shifts are required because cj = 0. Hence, to find all n of the integers abj2^j,j =0,1,...,n−1,requires at most
0+1+2+···+n−1 shifts. Hence, by Example 5 in Section 3.2 the number of shifts required is O(n^2).

> *
>
> **> To add the integers abj from j = 0 to j = n − 1 requires the addition
>
> > of an n-bit integer, an (n + 1)-bit integer, . . . , and a (2n)-bit
> >     integer. We know  that each of these additions requires O(n) additions
> >     of bits. Consequently, a total of O(n^2) additions of bits are
> >     required for all n additions***

Comment: This should probably be on [stack**overflow**](http://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: Or rather, [cs.se]. But definitely not in the present form. Please re-read and [edit].  (See: [How to ask a Good Question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959))